# Steps for age classification

Tags: algorithm, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am working on age (or gender) classification using images of human faces. I have decided to use the LBP (Local Binary Patterns) approach for feature extraction and Support Vector Machines (SVM) for freature classification. The whole process is shown in Fig. 1. Below.

As I understand it, the procedure is as follows:

1. Start with a training set that includes 3 groups: Chidren, Young, Senior. Each group has 50 images (150 images total). Use LBP to prepare the 150 images for classification.
2. Train a SVM on 150 LBP images with labels:

   - 0: Child
   - 1: Young Adult
   - 2: Senior
3. Test the system using a set of new images. If all goes according to plan, the system should properly classify images based on the groups defined in step 2.

The algorithm:

```
for i=1 to N //Assume N is number of image
   LBP_feature[i]=LBP_extract(image_i)
end
//Training stage
SVM.train(LBP_feature,label);
//Test stage
face=getFromCamera
//Extract LBP from the face
face_LBP=LBP_extract(face)
label=SVM.predict(face_LBP)
if label=0 then Children
if label=1 then Young
if label=2 then Senior
```

Does the proposed system make sense for this task?

[image]

Comment: what is your question ? Do *you* understand exactly the above steps ?

Comment: That means I am not sure about my understand. I just summarize what concept in the paper. Now, I want to implement it. Have any problem in my steps?

Comment: For example, I will choose opencv to implement age classification. And I must extract database image to LBP features and train these feature with SVM method (svm model). After that, I will extract LBP feature from an given image test. The LBP feature test will be input for svm model to predict  age. Is it right?

Comment: yes. sounds like a plan.

Comment: just saying, you will need to make histograms from small patches of the lbp image, and join those histograms for a feature vector, not use the lpb images per se.

Comment: very good point. Previous time, I just use LBP image that extract from raw image and put it to SVM train. Hence, the output is very bad. As you said, I will find the document to do it. Do you have any document about using histogram of a feature vector for training?

Comment: Why use an SVM? Convolutional neural networks tend to be better at these sorts of tasks + they learn their own features.

Comment: Actually, convolution neural networks is more difficult to implementation. If you know the reference in opencv. Please let me know. Thanks in advance

Comment: i don't think, you need a paper for that. just partition your lbp image into, say, 8x8 regions, make a histogram of each, and joint the resulting 64 histograms to a flat 1d Mat.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use support vector machines, and you also want to consider an image to be a "sample" of subregions, then so-called "support distribution machines" developed by Jeff Schneider and Barnabas Poczos might be best suited for your problem (paper and documentation available online). They actually showed that with some tweaks, support distribution machines outperformed all state-of-the-art methods for a certain popular image classification data set. They used SIFT (sp?) features and then each image was a collection of samples (subregion patches) from the feature space, and then "support distribution machines" are kernel-based SVMs that estimate a divergence kernel between two distributions by using a sample-based estimator.

If you want to use SVMs like support distribution machines, there is one final point to consider. SVMs are two-class classifiers. In order to extend to more than 2 classes, you can either train an SVM that classifies one class versus the union of the rest of the classes, for each choice of class (so N SVMs if you have N classes), and then you run each SVM and choose the class with the highest classification score. Another method, however, is to train an SVM for each pair of classes (so N(N-1)/2 SVMs for N classes) and then try to choose the best class by getting a "consensus" of all the pairwise comparisons. You can read about all this online and choose whichever method you think is best, or whichever method gives the best leave-one-out cross validation performance on the training data. (which should be easy to calculate because you only have 150 training points)

Answer (score 0):

On paper, the approach makes sense. The most important point is whether the LBP is the right feature for this task. You can first extract the LBP using different parameters (image size, bin count if you are using LBP histogram, etc.) and observe the data using a tool like Weka or R to see if your sample data for different classes exhibit different distributions.

You can also refer to a few research papers on age estimation to see what other features are suitable. I have tried Radon transform with some success, for seniors. The wrinkles in faces are well represented in Radon transform.